# Ubuntu 16.04 Nvidia Problem

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, login, 16.04

I did a Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install.  System uses Nvidia 980 GTX graphics card.  Everything works fine until I install nvidia drivers.  After I login it kicks me out to the login screen.

Tried `purge nvidia*` and then it logged in, but the desktop does not show up - just a blank background. Then I did `apt-get install nvidia-361` and it asked me to disable secure login and enter password.  I did that.  But it said I would have enter that password after reboot but it did not ask me for password after login.  Still can not login.  System worked in 15.04 before.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Solved by

1. purged nvidia*
2. did a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure compiz`

After that it worked for me.